# SQL how to convert row with date range to many rows with date range with gaps based on a data column

Tags: sql, date, group-by, date-range, gaps-and-islands

I want to convert data rows to date ranges in sql based on a column.
Below is the sample data:

[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buuTh.png)

```
FROMDATE    TODATE      Data
1/01/2010   31/10/2010  100
1/01/2011   31/12/2011  50
1/01/2012   31/12/2012  50
1/01/2013   31/12/2013  50
1/01/2014   31/12/2014  50
1/01/2015   12/10/2015  50
13/10/2015  31/12/2015  50
1/01/2016   21/02/2016  50
22/02/2016  31/12/2016  67
1/01/2017   2/10/2017   67
3/10/2017   31/12/2017  75
1/01/2018   31/03/2018  75
1/04/2018   30/06/2018  75
1/07/2018   31/10/2018  40
1/11/2018   31/12/2018  75
1/01/2019   31/03/2019  75
1/04/2019   31/12/2019  75
1/01/2020   1/03/2020   75
```

Required result is:

```
FROMDATE    TODATE      Data
1/01/2010   31/10/2010  100
1/01/2011   21/02/2016  50
22/02/2016  2/10/2017   67
3/10/2017   30/06/2018  75
1/07/2018   31/10/2018  40
1/11/2018   1/03/2020   75
```

[Required List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPQVS.png)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to give the credit to @Gordon Linoff whom one of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305315/sql-for-deleting-records-which-are-duplicateconsecutive-but-storing-there-min/63305353#63305353) helpmed me with Gaps and islands problems which i am just sharing with you.

*The reason I posted this as an answer due to the title which could be found in search results for this type of problems*

I have done it using Oracle database and it should work with all standard sql database. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1edc22de7a9326377d10c5e6907a974b) for reference

```
SELECT t.key_id
      ,MIN(fromdate)
      ,MAX(todate)
FROM   (SELECT t.*
              ,row_number() over(ORDER BY fromdate) AS startseq
              ,row_number() over(PARTITION BY t.key_id ORDER BY fromdate) AS endseq
        FROM   some_table t) t
GROUP  BY t.key_id
         ,(startseq - endseq);
```